# Wordpress: How can I mix my content background image with footer

Tags: images, css

Hi I am new to wordpress and I would like to know how can I fit my footer with my content background image?

What I want:
[image]

What I have now:
[image]

What I want to achieve is I want to put my footer content or in other words, I want the background image to be extend to footer.

Comment: If your theme doesn't support this design, then you would have to customize the footer template to do this and add custom css. I would not put that as a beginner skill level. Best that you seek a theme that supports a background image in the footer, or hire a developer to assist you.